# Comparing and transforming a date that is piped to (probably) awk?

Tags: shell, date, awk, pipe

I've got a reasonably complicated string of piped shell commands (let's assume it's `bunch | of | commands`), which together produces several rows of output, in this format:

`some_path/some_file.csv 1439934121`

...where `1439934121` is the file's last-modified timestamp.

What I need to do is see if it's a timestamp on the current day, i.e. on or after last midnight, and then include just the lines where that is true.

I assume this means that some string (e.g. the word `true`) should either replace or be appended to the timestamps of those lines for `grep` to distinguish them from ones where the timestamps are those of an earlier date.

To put it in shell command terms:

`bunch | of | commands | ????`

...should produce:

`some_path/some_file.csv true` or `some_path/some_file.csv 1439934121 true`

...for which I could easily `grep` (obviously assuming that `last midnight <= 1439934121 <= current time`).

What kind of `????` would do this? I'm almost certain that `awk` can do what I need it to, so I've looked at it and `date`, but I'm basically doing awk-by-google with no skills and getting nowhere.

Don't feel constrained by my tool assumptions; if you can achieve this with alternate means, given the output of `bunch | of | commands` but still using shell tools and piping, I'm all ears. I'd like to avoid temp files or Perl, if possible :-)

I'm using gawk + bash 4.3 on Ubuntu Linux, specifically, and have no portability concerns.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since `today 00:00:00` with the `%s` format returns the unix timestamp of that moment:

```
$ date -d'today 00:00:00'
Thu Sep  3 00:00:00 CEST 2015
$ date -d 'today 00:00:00' "+%s"
1441231200
```

You can probably pipe to an awk doing something like:

```
... | awk -v midnight="$(date -d 'today 00:00:00' '+%s')" '{$2= ($2>midnight) ? "true" : "false"}1'
```

That is, use the ternary operator to check the value of `$2` and replace with either of the values true/false depending on the result:

```
awk -v midnight="$(date ...)" '{$2= ($2>midnight) ? "true" : "false"}1'
```

#### Test

```
$ cat a
hello 1441231201
bye 23
$ awk -v midnight="$(date -d 'today 00:00:00' '+%s')" '{$2= ($2>midnight) ? "true" : "false"}1' a
hello true
bye false
```

Comment: Whoah, that was fast, and seems to work great. Thank you! Accepting as soon as SO allows me to :-)